# How to add another key/value to Firebase Array

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The problem that I'm facing is that I have successfully created the array and have displayed the values like so:

```
Users

-uid

   - Name: Example

   - Profile Pic URL: example12345

   - email: example@example.co.uk
```

However, in another swift file I have successfully generated a personality type and am struggling to add this to the array so that I end up with something that looks like this:

```
Users
 -uid

   - Name: Example

   - Profile Pic URL: 

   - email: example@example.co.uk

   - personality type: INTJ
```

I have tried copying the code from the previous swift class to no avail

This is the code for the working firebase array

```
 @IBAction func createAccountAction(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    let usersRef = Database.database().reference().child("Users")

    let userDictionary : NSDictionary = ["email" : emailTextField.text!, "Name": nameTextField.text!]

    if emailTextField.text == "" {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Please enter your email and password", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: self.emailTextField.text ?? "", password: self.passwordTextField.text ?? "") { (result, error) in
            if error != nil {


                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
                let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
                alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
                self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                return
            }
            guard let user = result?.user else { return }

            let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController
            self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
            // HERE YOU SET THE VALUES

            usersRef.child(user.uid).setValue(userDictionary, withCompletionBlock: { (error, ref) in
                if error != nil { print(error); return }


                let imageName = NSUUID().uuidString
                let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("profile_images").child("\(imageName).png")

                if let profileImageUrl = self.profilePicture.image, let  uploadData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.profilePicture.image!, 0.1) {
                    storageRef.putData(uploadData, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in

                        if error != nil, metadata != nil {
                            print(error ?? "")
                            return

                        }

                        storageRef.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in
                            if error != nil {
                                print(error!.localizedDescription)
                                return
                            }
                            if let profileImageUrl = url?.absoluteString {
                                   self.addImageURLToDatabase(uid: user.uid, values: ["profile photo URL": profileImageUrl as AnyObject])
                            }
                        })
                    })
                }
            }
        )}
    }
}
```

This is the other swift file function which generates the personality type which I would like to add to the array

```
   @IBAction func JPbtn(_ sender: Any) {


   if (Judging < Perceiving){
        Result3 = "P"
    } else {
        Result3 = "J"
    }


    let PersonalityType = "\(Result) \(Result1) \(Result2) \(Result3)"
    print(PersonalityType)

    let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Example") as! ViewController
  self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Answer (score 1):

So if you are just trying to add a new key with a value, all you need to do is create a new reference like this.

```
guard let currentUserUID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
print(currentUserUID)
let userPersonalityRef = Database.database().reference().child("users").child(currentUserUID).child("personality")
userPersonalityRef.setValue("Some Value")
```

When you set the value it can also be a dictionary if you want. But if your users don't all have personality make sure it optional on your data model or else It might crash your app. When you are getting your user from firebase.

Comment: Thank you! The logic makes sense I'll try the code and report back here

Comment: That code kept separating the arrays, I managed to fix the issue by using: update.ChildValue